# Mostrar iFrame completo

Tags: html, iframe

Buenas tengo una consulta a una BD y la muestro en iFrame el problema es que a veces devuelve 100 lineas otras 2.
Y quiero que el div cambie de tamaño segun las lineas...Si alguien podría mirarlo a ver que falla

```css
.filt{
    
        margin-left:100px;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 width: 75%;
 height: auto;
        background-color:#FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="filt">
    <div class="titl">
        <p>Direcciones</p>
    </div>
    <div class=contfiltros>
        <div class="tableDirec">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
            <table>  
                <tr>
                    <td width="10px">Ciudad</td>
                    <td width="10px" ><input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" value="" size="8"></td>
                    <td width="10px">CP</td>
                    <td  width="10px"><input type="text" id="cp" name="cp" value="" size="8"></td>
                    <td width="10px">Provincia</td>
                    <td width="10px"><input type="text" id="provincia" name="provincia" value="" size="8"></td>
                    <td width="10px">Comercial</td>
                    <td width="10px"><input type="text" id="comercial" name="comercial" value="" size="8"></td>
                    <td  width="10px"><a href="##"></a><button>Search</button></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>  
            </form>
             
              
                </tr>
               
               </div>
       
     
</div>
            <iframe src="CustomerMasterAddressResult.jsp" height="auto" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
   <%  }

        }

        sql.CloseConnection();
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba añadiendo estos cambios a tu hoja de estilos:

```
.filt{
      margin-left:100px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      background-color:#FAFAFA;
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

.filt iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No me o hace se superpone al div.